# Get all the work item id states in the same day

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I'm working in some work item id data, but I need all the states and the changed date from the work item ID. When I go in the *Analytics View* and created a table, it only shows the last state from the day and not all of them (so if they changed states a lot of time in the same day, I only get the last one).

Comment: Hi Anna,
How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks

Comment: Hi @YujunDing-MSFT . Yes, we are getting the data true API, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Azure Devops Queries, we do not support to get all work item id states in the same day. But we can use the Rest Api to help us.

First, we need to use the API: [Queries – Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to help us find the all work items which have been changed states in the same day.
Then, we need to use the Api: [Revisions – List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to help us find the all states history and then filter the states we need.

Here is the demo ps script to help you(On my test, I use the current data, you can also customer the time you like)

```
$token = "XXXXXXX"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$urlIds = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{ProjectName} /_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.0"

$currentTime = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd'

$JSON = @'
{
    
  "query": "select [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.AssignedTo], [System.State], [System.Tags] from WorkItems where [System.TeamProject] = @project and [System.WorkItemType] <> '' and [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate] = @today"

}
'@

$response2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlIds -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
$ids = $response2.workItems

foreach($id in $ids.id){
    $id.ToString()
    $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{ProjectName}/_apis/wit/workItems/"+$id+"/revisions?api-version=6.0"
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get -ContentType application/json
    $Test = $response.value.fields
    foreach($fields  in $Test){
        $date = $fields."System.ChangedDate"
        $clean = $date -replace '(T|Z),'
        $dateObject = [datetime]$clean
        If((get-date $currentTime) -lt (get-date $dateObject)){
            $fields."System.State".ToString()
            $dateObject.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test result with format(Workitem ID, states, change states time):

[image]